# Automated chrome shows different print window than regular one. How to receive this window for Cypress tests

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

I tried to find solution but I didn't managed ... so far I have tried couple of chrome settings and flags manipulation but it still doesn't work.

My problem here is that with Cypress I click on button "Print" which opens regular pint window (Operating System's). In regular Chrome it shows it as a pdf preview which is expected for my cypress tests.

I tested it with firefox and privew works for automatated chrome. IE doesn't.
[image]